# Consistent RAID 1 or equivalent solution across Windows, OS X, and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hard-drive, raid

I just built a new computer containing a 256 GB SSD and two 1 TB Seagate hard drives. I'm trying to find a good solution for having the two 1 TB drives mirrored, and keeping this mirroring working across Windows 8.1, OS X Mavericks, and Linux Mint 16.

Unfortunately, I've run into some severe limitations.

With a hardware RAID (Intel Rapid Storage on Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD4H), I first have the problem of having to reinstall Windows due to a change in SATA mode from AHCI to RAID. Another issue with this is that OS X only works with RAIDs using add-on cards, but this is an on-board hardware RAID.

A software RAID might be more effective, but in order for it to work with OS X I have to make all of the disks formatted with a GUID partition table, and I'm not yet aware of software RAID solutions for Windows.

The other option I've considered is using alternative software to make copies between the two disks. For example, I set OS X to use two Time Machines. The downfall is that they cannot both back up at once. Storage Spaces on Windows seemed like a good similar solution, but it only works with *entire* disks, not partitions. I'm also not yet aware of anything that works like that on Linux.

My question is: what's the best solution for me that doesn't require the purchase of additional hardware with the fewest disadvantages? I'm guessing that some sort of software RAID is my best bet, but I might be missing something here.

Comment: Intel Rapid Storage Technology is not hardware RAID, it is fakeraid. Linux and Windows can deal with fakeraid, but OS X cannot.

Comment: A real hardware RAID is the best.  For 2 drive mirroring you can get a cheap card.  You don't want to spend money, but there will be pain and suffering any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest solution would be to run OSX inside a VM hypervisor, and let Intel manage the volumes outside of the hypervisor so there are no problems. You can install the RAID driver for RST without an OS reinstall, it needs to be added to the OS prior to actually changing the driver for the device.

Additionally, Windows 7 has built in software RAID through dynamic disks. If you run Linux and OSX inside Windows, you can leave Intel out of it.

(assuming you are running Windows 7 pro)

If you are sharing the volume across multiple operating systems, you will run into different problems regarding file system support, or an OS making a change that another does not understand. NTFS support in non Windows operating systems is suboptimal. Windows does not support native access to HFS or EXT4 or BTRFS/ZFS. If I were in your position, I would let a single OS handle access to the disk and allow access to the others through SMB sharing over a VM network on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep that in mind if I decide to attempt this route again. I've decided to just leave the second drive as a non-RAID backup drive, and only place the Time Machine backup onto the first drive (since that will provide sufficient redundancy for an SSD failure). Since yours is the only answer, and likely a good one, I'll mark it.